# Proving injectivity of a piecewise defined function; slight conceptual issue

Tags: functions

I am having a slight issue wrapping my head around a specific concept in the following problem:

Let $A,B,C,D$ be sets such that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint and $C$ and $D$ are disjoint. Let $f:A\to C$ and $g:B\to D$ both be injective. Let $X,Y$ be sets such that $X=A\cup B$ and $Y=C\cup D$. Define $h:X\to Y$ by $$
h(x)=\begin{cases}
f(x), \text{if $x\in A$} \\ 
g(x), \text{if $x\in B$}
\end{cases} $$
Then $h:X\to Y$ is a function and is injective.

I get that, in order for $h$ to be a function, we had to specify that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, otherwise $h$ wouldn't be well-defined.

My question is this: when I pick some $x_1, x_2\in X$ to prove injectivity, I know that it is either the case that $x_1,x_2\in A$ or $x1,x2\in B$. It cannot be that $x_1\in A$ and $x_2\in B$ (or vice versa). But why is this?

Comment: That's not correct: You also need to check the case when $x_1 \in A$ and $x_2 \in B$, which is where the fact that $C$ and $D$ are disjoint gets used. The well-definition of $h$ does not have to do with the fact that $C$ and $D$ are disjoint.

Comment: Okay, so $A$ and $B$ being disjoint gives us that $h$ is well-defined (i.e. a function), and $C$ and $D$ being disjoint gives us that it must be that $x_1$ and $x_2$ belong to the same set. Is that correct?

Comment: Are you sure that it shouldn't be $f:A\to C$ instead of $f:A\to B$?  Similarly, $g:B\to D$.  As it currently stands the way you have written it, $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ need not necessarily be elements of $Y$, making the definition of $h$ potentiallly ill-defined.

Comment: Yes, that's my mistake. I edited the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for $h$ to be a function, it is useful to know that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint - otherwise, the definition on $A$ and the definition on $B$ could conflict. This does *not* depend on the fact that $C$ and $D$ are disjoint. After all, if we choose $A$ and $B$ to be your favorite disjoint sets and $C = \{0\} = D$ to have only one element, then $h$ is a perfectly well-defined constant function.

Now to show injectivity, you need to consider $x_1$ and $x_2$ as *any* pair of elements from $X$. They could both be in $A$, both be in $B$, or could have one from each. This leads to three separate cases, including the case that $x_1 \in A$ and $x_2 \in B$.

The fact that $C$ and $D$ are disjoint is used in this case, because $f(x_1) \in C$ and $f(x_2) \in D$ cannot be equal.

Comment: Ahh, yes. Because, as $f$ is injective, we'd have $x_1 = x_2$ and thus $x_1\in C$ and $x_1\in D$, which is impossible!

Comment: @kanker7 No, $x_1 \notin C$. But $f(x_1)$ is.

Comment: Yep, yep. My bad. Thank you!